# Google does not index my images (external server for images)

Tags: image, indexing, sitemap, robots.txt

We're trying to get our images on www.csselectronics.com to index properly on google. Unfortunately, Google Search Console only seems to index 3 images while several more have existed for a long time.

The issue may be due to my e-com platform using an external platform for uploading the images, e.g.:

https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/images.smoolis.com/460fc017-4c13-4dec-8f18-fce6cab6893f/large/CAN-Bus-Simple-Intro-Article-Monitor-Speed-Decoder-Analyse-Convert.jpg

Is there something I should change in my robot.txt file or something else I can do? The robot.txt looks as below:

## Build with Smoolis eCommerce platform

User-agent: *
Sitemap: https://www.csselectronics.com/script/sitemap/sitemap.xml
Disallow: /admin/
Disallow: /error
Disallow: /errors/
Disallow: /login
Disallow: /logout
Disallow: /internal/
Disallow: /process
Disallow: /process/
Disallow: /screenflow
Disallow: /screenflow/
Disallow: /workflow
Disallow: /workitem/
Disallow: /workspace/
Disallow: /JSON-RPC
Disallow: /keepalive
Disallow: /listener/
Disallow: /weblistener/

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your images are accessible by Google (i.e., crawlable), then it's probably because it can't figure out what these images are all about (no caption, no text around, etc...). Or Google does not find them interesting compared to what users are looking for or what it has already ranked.